# How to read state parameter from custom policies in AAD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are developing a web application using Azure AD B2C as the identity provider. For that we use custom policies and during the authentication flow, AAD B2C communicate with a REST API to get extended user claims.

Also, we want to pass value to the REST API from the client application. We were planning to use `state` parameter of the [Authorization Code Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow#1-get-an-authorization-code), to do that.
My question is how can we access that `state` parameter value via custom policies and so that we can pass that to the REST API as an `InputClaim`?

Comment: Looking here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview. I can't find state there :\ It's possible that it's just not available. Would it be possible to use a custom query parameter instead? You can try `{OAUTH-KV:state}` and `{OIDC:state}` I suppose.

Comment: Thank you @juunas. I have already tried `{OIDC:state}` and it is not supported. I just tried  `{OAUTH-KV:state}` as well. It didn't work either.  :/

Comment: The state isn’t meant for AAD B2C, it’s meant for your App. Why not use a custom query param?

Comment: I'm new to AAD B2C and actually didn't know that custom query param is being supported with AAD B2C. That should solve my concern.
Thank you both juunas and Jas Suri

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT I created a github issue to include details about custom query params to OIDC article: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/65795

Comment: Looks like this issue has been resolved right? Do you mind posting the answer?